# Log Management in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project in which I have to manage all the user activity logs or Notifications.
My problem is when user update any info that affects his previous logs or notifications as well.

example user updates his name today my app notify this to everyone but if he go back in previous logs or notifications, user name also get updated there which I don't want.

once the notification is generated in it should not be updated
but to achieve this I try to keep it separate but that give me redundant data in my database which i don't want.

What is the best solution for this ?

Comment: i dont get it... confusing

Comment: Can you please explain what tables and fields you are wanting to log changes from, and how you are storing / accessing these logs? There are a number of ways you could go about this, but we need more information to be able to make recommendations.